# "Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused" começando mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Instalei o mongodb como sugere no site oficial(*), iniciei o serviço, mas quando tentei usar o comando mongo no terminal foi retornado o seguinte erro:

```
2014-09-17T10:22:29.328-0300 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2014-09-17T10:22:29.329-0300 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com alguma solução?

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, você poderia criar / data / db na raiz . A documentação MongoDB sugere o seguinte comando para a criação `mkdir -p /data/db` .

Quanto à sua segunda pergunta, também sim . Desde o Mongo Daemon falhou ao iniciar e não está escutando você obter o erro de conexão.

Defaults MongoDB para /data/db para o diretório de dados. Você pode substituir o padrão usando a opção --dbpath no comando mongod.

Ou você poderia fazer algo assim:

1)  Remover o arquivo .lock

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
```

2) reparar o mongodb

```
mongod –repair
```

3) iniciar mongodb

```
sudo service mongodb start
```

4) iniciar mongo client

```
mongo
```

For more details take a look at http://shakthydoss.com/error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-srcmongoshellmongo-js-exception-connect-failed/

Comment: Otto, revisei minha ultima resposta

Comment: Prezado Otto, agradeço o auxílio. Consegui resolver com a sua ajuda e a ajuda de outros posts. Primeiro mudei o dbpath para minha pasta /home/username/data/db, pois meu diretório / estava sem espaço suficiente, depois dei chown para o usuário mongodb na pasta do dbpath e consegui iniciar o serviço. Agradeço a ajuda de todos, problema resolvido.

Comment: opa se pude ajudar em algo já é ótimo da um plus ai :D